# Automated installation with Brew/cask in apps folder

Tags: bash, shell, homebrew

I want create an automated script to use on a post installation.
For this reason i want use brew and cask to make it all.
So, i think that my script should start with that to install brew:

```
echo << "Installing homebrew..."
if test ! $(which brew); then
    echo "Homebrew not found, Installing..."
    ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
fi
```

Then i need to install some useful stuff as i see here:

http://lapwinglabs.com/blog/hacker-guide-to-setting-up-your-mac

So i put this too on my script:

```
# Install GNU core utilities (those that come with OS X are outdated)
brew install coreutils

# Install GNU `find`, `locate`, `updatedb`, and `xargs`, g-prefixed
brew install findutils

# Install Bash 4
brew install bash

# Install more recent versions of some OS X tools
brew tap homebrew/dupes
brew install homebrew/dupes/grep
$PATH=$(brew --prefix coreutils)/libexec/gnubin:$PATH
```

After that, the guide on the link says to install all the apps with cask and clean.
Here is my question.
I wish install and can update them in future using the classical Application folder of mac
How i can do that?

Maybe i should put this line:

```
export HOMEBREW_CASK_OPTS="--appdir=/Applications --caskroom=/usr/local/Caskroom"
```

Before all the commands to install the apps? May it works? (I have found this line here around)
If this line is correct can I update my apps using a brew/cask command?

Sorry for the dumbs questions, I've just discovered brew and cask yesterday :)
Any suggestion or example for this script is well accepted :)

Comment: "Just discovered cask today" through whatever random blog is no excuse for not reading the README, or running `man brew-cask`. https://github.com/caskroom/homebrew-cask/blob/master/USAGE.md .

Comment: Well, not exactly today, but some days ago, anyway my question is about scripting than caks itself :)

Comment: That first link sends us through a rabbit hole of redirections.

Answer (score 1):

`brew cask install <formula>` is supposed to symlink your app in `Applications` automatically.